# Refresh Team Provisioning Profile After Adding Devices For Distributing Archived Beta

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, provisioning, testflight

I have been having an issue wherein I add a device to the developer center, and it doesn't appear to be added to the provisioning profile for some time.  Then, there's no guarantee that the team provisioning profile is downloaded when I archive a build to distribute it to my beta testers (usually via TestFlight).

How can you forcibly update the provisioning profile so that all devices are included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode > Preferences > Account

At the right side ou will find a list of all your teams.. double click the desired one 
You will see a list of signing identities and provisioning profiles..
Theres is a refresh button =) BOTTOM LEFT side  =)

GL HF